# Haskell Reflex-Dom JSaddle error when stack building

Tags: haskell, reflex

Wanted to give Reflex-Dom a try but get an error from the jsaddle package when stack-building. Would love some tips on how to resolve this.

```
/private/var/folders/m2/qwhdrn_d46z99_3vxchdwn7r0000gn/T/stack6036/jsaddle-0.9.5.0/src/Language/Javascript/JSaddle/Types.hs:190:5-34: error:
    • No instance for (Control.Monad.Fail.MonadFail JSM)
        arising from a do statement
        with the failable pattern ‘SyncResult’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: SyncResult <- sendCommand Sync
      In the expression:
        do SyncResult <- sendCommand Sync
           return ()
      In an equation for ‘syncPoint’:
          syncPoint
            = do SyncResult <- sendCommand Sync
                 return ()
    |
190 |     SyncResult <- sendCommand Sync
    |
```

Cabal config:

```
executable reflexdom
  main-is: Main.hs
  other-modules:
      Paths_ReflexDom
  hs-source-dirs:
      app
  ghc-options: -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:
      ReflexDom
    , base >=4.7 && <5
    , reflex-dom >= 0.4 
    , reflex >= 0.5
  allow-newer: true
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

stack.yaml deps:

```
extra-deps: 
- reflex-0.5
- reflex-dom-0.4
- jsaddle-wkwebview-0.9.4.0
- ref-tf-0.4.0.1
- reflex-dom-core-0.4
- ghcjs-dom-0.9.2.0
- zenc-0.1.1
- ghcjs-dom-jsaddle-0.9.2.0
- jsaddle-dom-0.9.2.0
- jsaddle-0.9.5.0
```

allow-newer: true

Comment: Post edited. Learning Haskell but sometimes a little frustrated by errors like posted.

Comment: See what you can do with this. Happy hunting. https://github.com/mlitchard/reflex-todo

Comment: reflex is well above beginner haskell level. You are in bleeding edge territory.

Comment: You might try using the nix based install of the reflex-platform. Reflex has some specially curated dependencies that might be at the root of this. The nix install should take care of that. Also, the reflex channel on the irc has been a tremendous help, you might ping them there about this.

Comment: Also, if you do contact the reflex irc, please redirect them here. Reflex is awesome and I'd like to see more reflex tags appearing on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks I will definitely take up all your advise. Really welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The version of GHC you are using is too new, please use `lts-12` or lower.